# Show that the equation $\tan x=x$ has an infinity of solution

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

Given the function $f$ defined as :

1. for every $x \in (0,1]$ : $f(x)=x\sin(\frac{\pi}{x})$
2. $f(0)=0$

Show using roll's theorem that the equation $\tan x=x$ has an infinity of solutions

**What I have tried**

$f$ is differentiable in $(0,1]$

In $(0,1]$ we have $f(1)=\sin(\pi)=f(0)=0$

By Roll's : there exists $c \in(0,1)$ such that $f'(c)=0$

$$f'(x)=\sin(\pi/x)-x\cos(\pi/x)$$

In $(0,1)$ we have $f'(c)=\sin(\pi/c)-x\cos(\pi/c)=0$

so $\sin(\pi/c)=x\cos(\pi/c)$

Dividing by $\cos(\pi/c)$

we obtain $\tan(\pi/x)=x$

I am blocked here 
No problem if you give me any other information about an other way .

Comment: Note that actually _finding_ the solutions of $\tan(x) = x$ is way too hard. you're just supposed to show that there are infinitely many of them.

Comment: If you draw the graph of tangent and the graph of the identity function it is intuitively obvious.

Comment: Now that you have a lower bound on the number of solutions in $[0,1)$, can you lower bound the number of solutions in $[n, n+1)$ for $n \in \Bbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=x\sin \dfrac{\pi}{x}$ is differentiable on $(0,1].$ Moreover, we have that $f(1/n)=\dfrac{1}{n}\sin (n\pi)=0.$ So, we can apply Rolle's theorem on $\left[\dfrac{1}{n+1},\dfrac{1}{n}\right].$ Thus there exists $c_n\in\left(\dfrac{1}{n+1},\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$ such that $f'(c_n)=0.$ Or, equivalently, $\tan c_n=c_n.$ This shows that $\tan x=x$ has infinitely many positive solutions.

Answer (score 0):

For each $n\in\Bbb N=\{1,\ldots\}$, $f$ is differentiable on $(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n)$, continuous on on $[\frac1{n+1},\frac1n]$ and vanishes at the endpoints. By Rolle's theorem, there is $c_n \in (\frac1{n+1}, \frac1n)$ such that $f'(c_n)=0$. Now prove that $c_n \neq c_m$ for all $n\neq m$.

Note that the expression you got for $f'(x)$ is incorrect. It should be $\sin() -\frac{\pi}{x} \cos()$.

Answer (score -1):

Over arbitrary interval of definition tangent goes from minus infinity to infinity. That is, it goes from less than x to more than x (monotonically) Thus by intermediate value theorem it is the same as x precisely once on each interval of definition. There are infinitely many such intervals.

Comment: I can think of many functions going the whole way from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ without touching $y=x$

Comment: @OpenBall yeah but this is over a finite interval and continuously.

Comment: yeah but I think that a proof (or at least a reason) for why this necessitates that $\tan x$ cuts $x$ would make the answer better - as it stands, it is basically stating an incorrect thing.